# create a static sort of class counter in c++ (java example)

Tags: java, c++, class, static

here's the snippet in java:

```
class C {

    private static int c = 0;

    C(){ c++; }

    public static int getC () { return c; }
}

public class TestC {

    public static void main (...) {

        C c1 = new C();
        C c2 = new C();

        // at this point C.getC() returns 2(int)
    }
}
```

now I want to do something similar in C++, I have a basic understanding of class writing,
what should be the shortest snippet of code to implement the counter ?

here's my example class:

```
class C {

    public:


    private:
}

int main () {

    C c1;
    C c2;

    // printing the counter like C.getC();
}
```

Comment: @TedHopp do I really need to justify ?
if giving yourself some coding missions in order to level up in programming is similar to homeworking then yes consider that like "personal" homeworks.

Comment: Ohh, *that* sort of `static`... I had half expected something exiting with templates.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a justification. While it is perfectly acceptable to ask homework questions, they should be tagged as "homework". This helps responders tune their answers, as described in [this community wiki post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/156967).

Comment: @TedHopp ok sorry I misunderstood. but no it is not homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similar.

In relevant header:

```
class C {   
    private:
         static int c;  // Declaration of c.
    public:
         C(){ c++; }
         static int getC () { return c; }
};
```

In *one* `.cpp` file:

```
int C::c = 0;  // Definition of c.
```

It's crucial to provide the *definition* of c in exactly one place (i.e. not in  a header) or you will get linking errors.

Comment: Was writing exactly the same when you posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
class user
{
  private:
  int id;
  static int next_id;

  public:
  static int getCount()
  {    
    return next_id;
  }
  /* More stuff for the class user */
  user()
  {
    id = user::next_id++; //
  }
};
int user::next_id = 0;
```

from this link http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html